# Join table on get_where codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, join

I need to join a table and subtract from that table the position and pricebycat1 but i cannot figure out the function on codeigniter.

This is my function to retrieve the products.

```
function get_product($id, $related=true)
{
    $result = $this->db->get_where('products',array('id'=>$id))->row();
    // get position, pricebycat1, join category_products 'category_products.product_id=products.id'
    if(!$result) {
        return false;
    }
    $related = json_decode($result->related_products);
    if(!empty($related)) {
        //build the where
        $where = false;
        foreach($related as $r) {
            if(!$where) {
                    $this->db->where('id', $r);
            } else {
                    $this->db->or_where('id', $r);
            }
            $where = true;
        }
        $result->related_products = $this->db->get('products')->result();
    } else {
        $result->related_products = array();
    }
    $result->categories = $this->get_product_categories($result->id);
    // group discount?
    if($this->group_discount_formula) {
        eval('$result->price=$result->price'.$this->group_discount_formula.';');
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Be more clear about your problem please.

Comment: Yeah, this is really whacky code, it's really hard to figure out exactly what you're trying to achieve. Let us know what your DB structure is and how you're trying to tie these products together, because there has to be a better way. WTF is with the `eval()`, too?!

Answer (score 0):

You can't join another table using only `get_where()` .
Try to use this approach for extraction data

```
$this->db->select('*.products, category_products.position, category_products.price');
$this->db->from('products');
//join LEFT by default
$this->db->join('category_products', 'category_products.product_id=products.id');
$this->db->where('products.id = '.$id);
$this->db->row();
```

Comment: Not true - you can do a `join()` before `get_where()` just fine. Just not sure if that's suitable for the OP.

Comment: See how `get_where()` function realized in CI. It won't work. Could you give your example of it?

Comment: As I said, put `join()` before `get_where()`. No, you can't join using get_where all by itself, but you can chain active record stuff before get_where.